# $f$ integrable $\Leftrightarrow f<\infty$ a.s.?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, proof-verification

$f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ measurable function on measure space$(\Omega,\mathfrak{A},\mu)$. I am interested to know if then 
$$
f\text{ is integrable }\Leftrightarrow f\text{ is finite a.s.}~~~.
$$

To my thoughts this equivalence is false in general.

*Proof*:

"$\Rightarrow$": $f$ integrable, i.e. $\int_{\Omega}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu<\infty$. $N:=\left\{f=\infty\right\}$, then $\Omega=N\uplus N^C$.
$$
\infty >\int_{\Omega}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu=\underbrace{\int_N\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu}_{=\infty\cdot\mu(N)}+\underbrace{\int_{N^C}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu}_{\in [0,\infty)}\Rightarrow \mu(N)=0
$$

To my opinion "$\Leftarrow$" is **not** true in general, because by $\mu(N)=0$ alone, it does not follow that the integral $\int_{N^C}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu$ is finite and so $\int_{\Omega}\lvert f\rvert\, d\mu$ is in general not finite.

---

So only: $f$ integrable$\implies f$ finite a.s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct: If $f$ is integrable, it's finite almost surely. To justify that the other direction isn't true, just find a counterexample: if we consider $[0, 1]$ equipped with the usual Lebesgue measure,

$$f(x) = \frac 1 x$$

is not integrable, although it's finite on $(0, 1]$.

Comment: Thank you, that's a good counterexample!

Comment: An even simpler counter example is the constant function $f=1$, so long as $\mu(\Omega)=\infty$.

Comment: @Unwisdom Indeed, although that example can't be directly adapted for use in a probability space.

Answer (score 0):

If $a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\in(0,\infty)$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots=\infty$ then $\displaystyle\int_{(0,\infty)} a_{\lfloor x\rfloor} \, dx = \infty$.